# File header comments showing extra lines

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, templates, comments

I have followed this [post](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/changing-xcode-header-comment/) for configuring file header comment template. But when I open a new file I find `//` at the beginning of the file. I don't want that line.

My `IDETemplateMacros.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
      <key>FILEHEADER</key>
      <string></string>
   </dict>
</plist>
```

Output in a new file:

```
//

import Foundation
```

Where `//` is came from?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode automatically provides a leading comment sequence (`//`) before adding the contents of the `FILEHEADER` entry.

Xcode also does not check to see if your `FILEHEADER` data starts with a comment sequence, so anyone making customer headers must remove the first comment sequence to prevent getting a double sequence (which may turn a comment into a documentation comment.)

Comment: what if i really want to add documentation comment with FILEHEADER? no way to remove it? :(

Comment: I do not know of a way to remove the part added by Xcode.  But you can just use a blank line for first line and start whatever kind of text you want on the next lines.